# Scala macros - storing global state?

Tags: scala, macros

Is it possible for a macro implementation to maintain some form of global state (during the entire compilation run)? Specifically, I want to create a separate instance of `IMain`, but I don't want to create it anew in every macro expansion, so I would like to have a form of `lazy val`, `ThreadLocal` or anything where I can cache that instance. For simplicity, just imagine I want to share an object during compilation between all expansions of the same macro:

```
object Foo {
  def next: Int = macro ???
}

trait Test {
  val a = Foo.next
  val b = Foo.next
  val c = Foo.next
  assert(a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 3)
}
```

Since in the actual case, the state is quite complex and not serializable, reading and writing to disk is not an option.

I can't seem to see any way to achieve that through the only context provided, `scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context`. Does that mean I have to write a full-fledged compiler plugin? Can I trick sbt into giving me some object I can write to?

Comment: Complete guess, but does a `var` in an `object` in the same unit as the macro work?

Comment: @HTNW oh brilliant, so simple, yes that works! Can you post as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `object` and a `var`. As long as the file it's in doesn't use your macros, it should work. I'm not sure if it's ever guaranteed anywhere that `scalac` will keep the state of macros between units, but this seems to work for you.

```
object Foo {
  def next: Int = macro next_impl
  var state = ???;
  def next_impl(...): ...
}
```